# Simpler version of capitalizing each word in a string

Tags: javascript

I have this code which does the job, however it seems to me that the same could be done with less code. And why if I put 'var newString = stored.join(' ');' below 'var stored=[];' the code doesn't work?

```
function titleCase(str) {

var lower = str.toLowerCase();

var arr = lower.split(' ');

var stored = [];

//takes a string from arr
for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {

 //splits and stores the string to letters 
   var word = arr[i].split(''); // ['l','i','t'...]

    // takes the first letter from the array and makes it uppercase
   for(var k=0; k<1; k++){
   var upper = word[k].toUpperCase(); 
   word.shift(); 
   word.unshift(upper);
   var joined = word.join('');
   stored.push(joined);
}

}
 var newString = stored.join(' ');

 return newString;

}

 titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
```

Comment: What would be the output of `titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");`?

Comment: You mean it doesn't work when you move the `var newString = stored.join(' ');` above the loop? Well obviously that's because the array isn't yet filled.

Answer (score 4):

You can use String#replace with a regexp:

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  return str.toLowerCase() // change the string to lowercase
    .replace(/\S+/g, function(s) { // get all non space characters sequences
      return s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1); // uppercase the 1st letter and combine with the rest of the string
    });
}

console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string by space, then use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to iterate over words and uppercase each word and then [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) it back again:

```
"I'm a little tea pot"
  .split(' ')
  .map(function(word) {
    return word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substring(1);
  })
  .join(' ');
```

Comment: huh...so the argument 'word' in the function is the current value being procesed? And by 'word[0]' it takes the first letter of the word? I thought that you have to use '[ ]' only on an array. Or that value being processed becomes an array somehow? Sorry for dumb questions...

Answer (score 2):

A more succinct string replace variant:

```
   str.replace (/(^|\s)\S/g, match => match.toUpperCase () );
```

The regexp matches the satrt of string or a space followed by a non-space character. The entrire match is up-cased and returned.

Comment: Consider using `\b` instead of `(^|\s)`. Not only is it simpler, it also has the advantage of working with words that follow punctuation (such as a double-quote).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of providing a complete solution like the other answers (migrated from SO), I'll point out a few specific things that could be improved:

> ```
> //splits and stores the string to letters 
> var word = arr[i].split(''); // ['l','i','t'...]
> ```

That's not really necessary. You can used indexed access, a `length` property and the same iteration on the string itself.

> ```
> // takes the first letter from the array and makes it uppercase
> for(var k=0; k<1; k++){
>   var upper = word[k].toUpperCase();
> ```

Why is this a loop? It loops exactly once, testing whether `0 < 1`. Just drop that and place

```
var upper = word[0].toUpperCase();
```

> ```
> word.shift(); 
> word.unshift(upper);
> ```

Don't do that. It move the whole array around and then back. Just assign to the first index:

```
word[0] = upper;
```

> ```
> var joined = word.join('');
> ```

If we didn't split the `arr[i]` word in the `word` array, we could instead use

```
var joined = arr[i][0].toUpperCase() // upper 
           + arr[i].slice(1); // the rest of the string
```

> ```
> var stored = [];
> //takes a string from arr
> for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
>   …
>   stored.push(joined);
> }
> ```

Instead of filling that `stored` array, you could have mutated the original one (for a tiny bit of better performance). But creating a new array is fine.

However, when creating a new array with one item per item from the original array, the [`map` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) helps a lot to remove the boilerplate loop, array instantiation and pushing.

> ```
> var lower = str.toLowerCase();
> var arr = lower.split(' ');
> …
> var newString = stored.join(' ');
> return newString;
> ```

Since you specifically asked about doing it with less code: use less variables. If you only use a variable exactly once, the expression might as well be inlined:

```
var arr = str.toLowerCase().split(' ');
…
return stored.join(' ');
```

It's often beneficial for clarity to use more of such descriptive variable names, but it also is a lot longer.

If you apply all these points, you'll basically end up with madox2's solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the regex `/([^ ]+)/g` to match for each word and then change the first letter.

```js
var titleCase = (text) => text.replace(/([^ ]+)/g, (w) => w[0].toUpperCase() + w.substring(1));

console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change the regex to only match the first character in a word instead of using a concatenation like others did:

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  return str.replace(/(^|\s)\w/g, (s) => s.toUpperCase() );
}

console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

However there are some questions you might want to consider. For example a newspaper would not capitalize a (or an or the) and hyphenated words are (High-Quality) are sometimes capitalized.

Comment: Use `[a-z]` instead of `\w`. `\w` = `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.